# Arango: changing config in MacOSX does not change endpoint

Tags: arangodb

I have have just downloaded arango with a

```
brew install arangodb
```

the symlink component of installation failed, since brew no longer enables this for what seem to be good reasons.

Next, I modify

```
/usr/local/etc/arangodb3/arangosh.conf
/usr/local/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf
```

to point at `localhost:####` and yet all arango db executables still attempt to connect to the default IP address, and do not connect to the localhost.

How do I motivate this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the files only is not enough. Please restart the service. 
`/usr/local/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf` is the correct file though.